# How to use angular js 1 select box options with ng-if condition and ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Angular js1 inside the select box ng-if is not working.How to i solve this problem? i will show the name of john only in view page with the if condition.how to i show it?

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [
    {name:"john",
    area:"India"
    }, 
    {name:"Apple",
       area:'US'
    }, 
    {name:"Ravi",
          area:"UK"
     }];
    
    $scope.clicked=function(){
    alert("hello");
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<select>
<option ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="clicked()"     ng-if="item.area=='India'">{{item.name}}</option>
</select>

</div>
```

Comment: what exactly do you want to do? please explain?

Comment: i  think you want to filter the data according to the area name . am i right ?

Comment: @Viplock yes i want to Filter John only and  i want to ng-click event also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [
    {name:"john",
    area:"India"
    }, 
    {name:"Apple",
       area:'US'
    }, 
    {name:"Ravi",
          area:"India"
     }];
    $scope.selected={}
    $scope.clicked=function(){
     alert("hello");
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<select>
<option ng-repeat="item in items|filter:{area:'India'}" ng-click="clicked()"   >{{item.name}}</option>
</select>

Better way-
<select ng-options="option.name for option in items|filter:{area:'India'}" ng-model="selected" ng-change="clicked()" >
</select>

</div>
```

You can filter the data according to area with using filter check `ng-repeat` .

if the area name is coming dynamically , change the filter accordingly.

**EDIT**
Use [ng-change](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) directive not ng-click(See the changes)

Comment: thank you for your answer.but ng-click event is not working.it possible to use ng-click in select box?

Comment: see the changes i made